# How do I fix PHP code that appears at top of webpage?

Tags: php, html

When I open my webpage the php code appears at the top of the page. When I try and test page I run a 'test' php' page.

However when the 'test' code is run the page is blank. Any idea what the problem could be and how this could be fixed.

Test code:

```
<html> <body> <?php show_source("test.php"); ?> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Test code look as follows:  <html>
<body>
<?php
show_source("test.php");
?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: How you open or run this file? through xamp/wamp or directly to the browser?

Comment: I use Mozilla Firefox 74.0.1 and run the code directly on the browser - http://localhost/filename